How do I make my PSQL which is ahead of my prisma migration to be in sync with it without clearing the db
so I have a schema model called Appointment with some fields, with those fields I was able to create multiple roles for the appointment table, I then made a change by adding "status" to the Appointment table directly to the psql query tool, I then add the status to the schema model. I need to make a migration now and Prisma is detecting the disparity between my migration history and my db. I do I make my db in sync with my Prisma migrations without clearing the db, like git where if the remote repo is ahead of the local repo, a simple git pull will bring them in sync. How do I go about this?

You messed up by editing the DB schema manually. That's what the migrations are for. Here is the documentation you need: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-migrate/workflows/troubleshooting

Step 1: in local environment you export data to .sql file. After that clear data, add "status" (need to set default if status is required) and run migrate to generate migrate file (yarn prisma generate dev).
Step 2: run .sql (saved before) then run (yarn prisma migrate deploy).
Note: In production environment only run yarn prisma migrate deploy (not need clear old data)
